# Recursive function does not exit prematurely

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a recursive function to find a treeitem in the treeview from its name.

```
bool SumCommandInterface::getTreeItem(const std::string &stdstrName, const QModelIndex & index, TreeModel *model, TreeItem** item)
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        TreeItem* currentTreeItem = model->getItem(index);
        if (currentTreeItem->getName() == stdstrName)
        {
            *item = currentTreeItem;
            return true;            
        }
    }

    if(!model->hasChildren(index) || (index.flags() & Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren))
    {
        return false;
    }


    auto rows = model->rowCount(index);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        getTreeItem(stdstrName , model->index(i, 0, index), model , item );

    return false;
}
```

The function still runs even after it satisfies the condition.

Comment: You should consider the return value of the recursive function call too. I.e. write it like `return getTreeItem(...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in you code is that you don't return from the function even if a recursive function call returns `true`, i.e. when the condition is met. The right way to implement the recursive call would be:

```
[..]
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    // Return if the condition is met.
    if (getTreeItem(stdstrName , model->index(i, 0, index), model, item)) {
        return true;
    }
[..]
```